# how to compile ubuntu kernel faster

Tags: kernel, compiling

I'm following this guideline from ubuntu wiki:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel

But when i run

```
fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic
```

it takes a long time because it compiles the entire kernel.

I tried running

```
fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic -j8
```

but it didn't seem to do anything. How do i tell the machine to run this command using 8 cores? Or is there another way to speed up the compilation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `CONCURRENCY_LEVEL` variable for that.

Run the command this way

```
CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=8 fakeroot debian/rules binary-headers binary-generic
```

This variable is set to the number of CPUs automatically.